# Python logging set log path during runtime when running spark job in cluster mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My logging setup looks something like this
logging.json contains logging config

```
File Handler:
filename: "%dynamic_log%/sample.log"
```

I'm constructing dynamic log path during run time, and replacing %dynamic_log% with actual path where I want to log and loading into logger using dictConfig.

Heres the problem, when running the pyspark job in cluster mode. Driver executes the spark job in one of the worker node container.
Its searching for the dir path on the worker node and I'm getting

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or dir:  'my/dynamic/path/sample.log'
```

Workaround:

In logging.json

```
File Handler:
filename: "sample.log"
```

which creates the sample.log file is the worker node then I'm copying the log file to the dynamic path after the job completes using Hadoop FileSystem.
`fs.moveFromLocalFile('sample.log", "my/dynamic/path/sample.log")`

which is not ideal, as I won't be able to see logs while the job is running.

I tried creating log file first then write the logs using

```
fs.create(my/dynamic/path/sample.log)
```

sample.log is created in the actual dir but still getting error `No such file or dir:  'my/dynamic/path/sample.log`'

Thank you in advance (sorry for the bad format)

Answer (score 0):

We can attempt to generate the log to a specific location (perhaps not dynamic) using spark and log4j.properties supplied to spark-submit using `extraJavaOptions` param with Dlogger.File value.

something like below:

```
spark-submit --master local --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dlogger.File=/tmp/sample.log -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/log4j.properties" --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dlogger.File=/tmp/sample.log -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/log4j.properties" main.py
```

while a similar attempt can be put up through a spark properties setting in the main (not sure if this goes through).

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('logger.File', '/tmp/sample.log')
logger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger('default')
```

and defining log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, spark_jobs
log4j.logger.spark_jobs=INFO
log4j.appender.spark_jobs.File=${logger.File}
```

For a dynamic path I guess the catch is PySpark under the hood invokes Py4J(JVM) so we might need a mechanism to set up the properties while the JVM boots up.